# Properly extending classes from existing classes, design pattern?

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I am trying to figure out the best way to create new classes that share common functionality from existing classes which inherit from each other, the classes which I am working from

```
Actor

Group extends Actor
```

These classes cannot be changed in any way shape or form as they are from jar files.

I started by adding my own functionality to these classes by simply

```
MyActor extends Actor
MyGroup extends Group
```

But I found that I was repeating alot of code as both of My(Classes) are essentially actors.

How do I java have a class which both MyActor and MyGroup can inherit from whilst also ensuring that they inherit from Actor and Group respectively.

Thansk

Comment: Which version of Java?

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this problem by making Actor and Group interfaces, this way you can declare methods and variables, and still fill them in differently in each class if need be, you could also make only one of the an interface. It's up to you really. I'd make Group an interface though.

Comment: This would mean repeating the same code though, it would enforce a method contract which is a good start though. Thanks.